# Converting a triple integral for evaluation

Tags: cylindrical-coordinates

I'm trying to evaluate the following triple integral.

$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{16-x^2}} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{16-x^2-y^2}} \text{dz dy dx}
$

It looks to me like I'll probably need to convert it to cylindrical coordinates in order to evaluate it but I'm not sure how to

Comment: If $x$ goes from $0$ to $4$ see the answer below. Otherwise, if $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$ (as you have written) it's a little bit more work, you need to split the integral.

Answer (score 1):

You could still carry out the triple integral as it is, without resorting to the cylindrical coordinates. It is actually easier.

After integration over $z$,

$$
I=\int_{0}^{1}dx \int_{0}^{\sqrt{16-x^2}} \sqrt{16-x^2-y^2} dy
$$

The resulting $y$-integral can be performed with integration-by-parts as,

$$
\int_{0}^{a} \sqrt{a^2-y^2} dy = \frac{1}{2}\left[ y\sqrt{a^2-y^2}+a^2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{a}\right) \right]_{y=0}^{y=a}= \frac{a^2}{4}\pi
$$

where $a^2=16-x^2$. In the end, the integral over $x$ becomes,
$$
I=\frac{\pi}{4} \int_{0}^{1} (16-x^2)dx = \frac{47}{12}\pi
$$

Comment: Do you think you could help me understand the second line a little bit better? A reference to some material on the technique would probably be sufficient!

Comment: Do you refer to integral-by-parts for $y$?

Comment: I think so, the part where the a^2*inv(tan) comes in

Comment: Actually, $\tan^{-1}(y/\sqrt{a^2-y^2}) =\sin^{-1}\left(y/a)\right)$. So, simplified the $y$-integral in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the bounds for $x$ were $0\le x\le 4$ then the region of integration was part of a sphere with radius $4$ centered at the origin in the first octant

The integral evaluates the volume of that region therefore it is $$ \frac {1}{8} \frac {4\pi (4^3)}{3}=\frac {32\pi }{3}$$

However with $0\le x \le 1$ we split the integral into two parts. 
  Let $\alpha =\pi/2-\sin^{-1}(1/4)$, then $$I=I_1+I_2$$
$$I_1=\int _0^\alpha \int _0^{\sec(\theta ) } \sqrt {1-r^2}r dr d\theta$$

$$I_2=\int _\alpha ^{\pi/2} \int _0^4 \sqrt {1-r^2}rdrd\theta$$

Comment: $x$ is from $0$ to $1$

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{16-x^2}} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{16-x^2-y^2}} \mathrm d z \,\mathrm d y \,\mathrm d x=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{16-x^2}}\sqrt{16-x^2-y^2} \mathrm d y \,\mathrm d x.$$

This may be done directly. Set $\sqrt{16-x^2}=a,$ then the integral becomes $$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{a}\sqrt{a^2-y^2} \mathrm d y \,\mathrm d x.$$ Now make the usual substitution $y=a\sin\phi,$ which makes the inner integral elementary, so that the whole integral becomes $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{πa^2}{4}\text{d} x=\frac π4 \int_{0}^{1} {16-x^2}\text{d}x,$$ which is obviously elementary.

Comment: if a = root(16-x^2) I don't think you can make the substitution you did under the radical unless I'm mistaken

Comment: @financial_physician Why not? If $\sqrt {16-x^2}=a,$ then $16-x^2=a^2.$

Comment: Oh, I see now! It definitely works. For whatever reason I was thinking we were trying  to say root(a) - root (y^2) = root(a - y^2) but now that I'm looking at it again I was entirely wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @financial_physician Oh, it would have been absurd for one to say that $\sqrt x -\sqrt y =\sqrt{x-y}.$ That's complete nonsense! :)